# selector column table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello everyone I hope you can help me

I have the code that I need to do this by column. It currently just lets me select a number, not all.

I have tried in various ways, but I still can not find the solution.

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row_number").bind("click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).css("background-color") != "rgb(26, 179, 148)") {
      $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(26, 179, 148)");
      $(this).css("color", "white");
    } else {
      $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,255)");
      $(this).css("color", "#676a6c");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table-exam" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="11">ESCALA DE COMA DE GLASGOW </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Respuesta Motora</th>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Respuesta Verbal</th>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Apertura Ocular</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="text-center" colspan="2">OBEDECE</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" data-number="1" colspan="2">6</td>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="3">ORIENTADO</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" colspan="2">5</td>
    <td class="text-center">EXPONTANEA</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="2">LOCALIZA</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" data-number="1" colspan="2">5</td>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="3">DESORIENTADO</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" colspan="2">4</td>
    <td class="text-center">A LA VOZ</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number">3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I can't understand your explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar In the first column the numbers 6 and 5 are shown if you click on one of them you select what I need is that I only let me select a number by column that is to say that in that column I only let me select the 6 or the 5

Comment: FYI: You should stop using `.bind()`, it has been deprecated. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: I still can't understand what you want. Do you have a friend who speaks English better?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select the entire column of numbers(Example: col with 6,5) by clicking on any of the two cells containing those numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

> In the first column the numbers 6 and 5 are shown if you click on one of them you select [it] - what I need is that it only lets me select a single number per column, that is to say that in that column it only lets me select the 6 or the 5

This also assumes that

> you want to keep your existing HTML

(see @ksav's answer for an alternative that uses `data-` attributes to group similar data)

When you select/click one, it needs to turn off any others.  This is much easier using classes than setting colours directly:

```
$(".row_number").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".row_number").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

this will work for all `.row_number`, but your requirement is / appears to be within a single column, which is a bit trickier:

You need to find which column has been clicked, then remove the class from only cells in that column:

```
var col = $(this).closest("td").index() + 1;
$("#table-exam tr td:nth-child(" + col + ")").removeClass("selected");
```

Giving:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row_number").on("click", function(e) {
    var col = $(this).closest("td").index() + 1;
    $("#table-exam tr td:nth-child(" + col + ")").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  })
})
```

```css
.selected { background-color: rgb(26,179,148); color:white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table-exam" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="11">ESCALA DE COMA DE GLASGOW </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Respuesta Motora</th>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Respuesta Verbal</th>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Apertura Ocular</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="text-center" colspan="2">OBEDECE</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" data-number="1" colspan="2">6</td>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="3">ORIENTADO</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" colspan="2">5</td>
    <td class="text-center">EXPONTANEA</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="2">LOCALIZA</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" data-number="1" colspan="2">5</td>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="3">DESORIENTADO</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" colspan="2">4</td>
    <td class="text-center">A LA VOZ</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number">3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row_number").bind("click", function(e) {
    const type = $(this).data('type')
    const $sameOfType = $('[data-type="' + type + '"]')
    $sameOfType.removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected')
  })
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table-exam" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="11">ESCALA DE COMA DE GLASGOW </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Respuesta Motora</th>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Respuesta Verbal</th>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Apertura Ocular</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="text-center" colspan="2">OBEDECE</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number " data-number="1" colspan="2" data-type="motora">6</td>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="3">ORIENTADO</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number " colspan="2" data-type="verbal">5</td>
    <td class="text-center">EXPONTANEA</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number " data-type="ocular">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="2">LOCALIZA</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" data-number="1" colspan="2" data-type="motora">5</td>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="3">DESORIENTADO</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" colspan="2" data-type="verbal">4</td>
    <td class="text-center">A LA VOZ</td>
    <td class="text-center row_number" data-type="ocular">3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```